# How to use ReactiveUI MessageBus Pattern to comunicate between two UserControls?

Tags: wpf, reactiveui

I'm trying to work with ReactiveUI framework in wpf project.
In detail I'm trying to use the MessageBus pattern to comunicate between two different viewmodel. 
In the simplified example below I try to update MainWindowView Label when I click on the UserControl Button insert into MainWindowView. The Button click is managed by ReactiveUI BindCommand that call UserControlViewModel method. This method send a message by MessageBus ReactiveUI mechanism.
The MainWindowViewModel listen message and update the Label caption on MainWindowView that show the title of the window. I don't know why this doesn't work.

Below there are the the code:

MainWindowView (Xaml):

```
<rxui:ReactiveWindow x:Class="TestMessageBus.MainWindowView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestMessageBus"
        xmlns:rxui="http://reactiveui.net"
        x:TypeArguments="local:MainWindowViewModel"             
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label x:Name="TitleLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <local:UserControlView/>
    </StackPanel>
</rxui:ReactiveWindow>
```

MainWindowView (Code Behind):

```
namespace TestMessageBus
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindowView : ReactiveWindow<MainWindowViewModel>
    {
        public MainWindowView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();

            this.WhenActivated(disposable =>
            {
                this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Title, v => v.TitleLabel.Content)
                    .DisposeWith(disposable);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel:

```
namespace TestMessageBus
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ReactiveObject
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {

            MessageBus.Current.Listen<string>("Contract1").Subscribe(x => MessageSend(x));

        }

        private void MessageSend(string title)
        {
            Title = title;
        }
    }
}
```

UserControlView (Xaml):

```
<rxui:ReactiveUserControl x:Class="TestMessageBus.UserControlView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestMessageBus"
             xmlns:rxui="http://reactiveui.net"
             x:TypeArguments="local:UserControlViewModel" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="200">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="ButtonTest">TEST</Button>
    </Grid>
</rxui:ReactiveUserControl>
```

UserControlView (Code behind):

```
namespace TestMessageBus
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControlView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControlView : ReactiveUserControl<UserControlViewModel>
    {
        public UserControlView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ViewModel = new UserControlViewModel();

            this.WhenActivated(disposable =>
            {
                this.BindCommand(ViewModel, vm => vm.ClickCommand, v => v.ButtonTest).DisposeWith(disposable);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

UserControlViewModel:

```
namespace TestMessageBus
{
    public class UserControlViewModel: ReactiveObject
    {
        public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> ClickCommand { get; set; }

        public UserControlViewModel()
        {
            ClickCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(ClickButton);


        }

        private void ClickButton()
        {
            MessageBus.Current.SendMessage("TITOLO", "Contract1");
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect to see the "TITOLO" string in the MainWindow Label but this doesn't happen. Someone can explain me why? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First I want to note, that even though the framework provides a MessageBus implementation, we don't recommend it's use.

I don't see you Registering a message source anywhere in your example.

You should have a call somewhere to `RegisterMessageSource` which takes an `IObservable` and in this case I would gather it should be your button click.

something like:

```
MessageBus.Current.RegisterMessageSource(ButtonTest.Events().Clicked)
```

Where `Events().Clicked` is just an Observable wrapper around the button click event.

There is an example on the [ReactiveUI Website](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/message-bus/#message-bus)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Which alternative approach do you suggest for achieve the same result  in better way?

Comment: I read in the reactiveUI website that is better use WhenAny approch. By I don't understand how to apply this to my example. Could someone help me?Thanks very much.

Comment: You're using the Message Bus to pass a message that the observable can pass just by existing.  Use an observable that both have access to.

If there is a wrapping ViewModel that needs information, simply expose a `UserControlViewModel` from the `MainViewModel`.  That way the MainViewModel can interact directly with the observable that is providing updated values.

Comment: I'm new in ReactiveUI and I can't figure your advice. Could you show me a simple track applied on my example. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have tried to use Splat service locator for do my job. Is the correct method? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is one potential approach, but I'm not sure if it fits with Reactive UI best practice. The issue for me is that `Subject` smashes the `IObservable` and the `IObserver` together.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        private static string GetSomeData() => "Hi";

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task TestMethod8()
        {
            var subject = new Subject<string>();

            //Create a class and inject the subject as IObserver
            new Publisher(subject);

            //Create a class and inject the subject as IObservable
            new Subscriber(subject);
            new Subscriber(subject);
            new Subscriber(subject);

            //Run the loop for 10 seconds
            await Task.Delay(10000);
        }

        class Publisher
        {
            public Publisher(IObserver<string> observer)
            {
                Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    //Loop forever
                    while (true)
                    {
                        //Get some data, publish it with OnNext and wait 500 milliseconds
                        observer.OnNext(GetSomeData());
                        await Task.Delay(500);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        class Subscriber
        {
            //Listen for OnNext and write to the debug window when it happens
            public Subscriber(IObservable<string> observable) => observable.Subscribe((s) => Debug.WriteLine(s));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Then I don't use Messagebus pattern method but Splat service locator. When you write that is not the Reactive UI best practice, do you refer to the messagebus method or splat service method?

Comment: You should be using NSubstitute for the "IMessageBus" interface and do a "Received()" or "DidNotRecieved()". No need to write a console app into a test method